# Apps.ycombinator.com section list

Tags: hacker-news

What exactly does the apps.ycombinator section list versus the normal news.ycombinator section.

For example I know news.ycombinator.com/ask lists all the "Show HN" and "Ask HN" questions.

I assumed apps should be showing recently updated applications but it looks the same as news.yc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, someone already asked this on Hacker News [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1181897).

Paul Graham's response was:

> Another name for news, left over from a time when news had so few users that it would have seemed odd to use news urls for people applying to YC.